# is there any Ubuntu 15.10 USB 3 or USB-C to HDMI adapter that works

Tags: drivers, usb, hdmi

Hi I bought the latest Dell XPS 13 2015 and installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it. The laptop has two USB 3 ports and one USB-C port (no thunderbolt port or anything)

I'm looking for for an adapter to HDMI that would work. I would appreciate if someone who got it work on his/her Ubuntu 15.10 reply.

Sofar I have these options

- Display Link has some drivers for Ubuntu 14.04 http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php but the problem is that they are ment for kernel 3.x so unless  I backport older kernel (as I'm ubuntu 15.10) and do some changes in the instalation file it doesn't work
- brand V.Top has USB 3 to hdmi that they say it work with Ubuntu but it doesn't (bought one and it doesn't work... long story short, they pointed me to "try to" install Displaylink drivers, doesn't work)

so I'm ok with installing  drivers and stuff but anyone know about any adapter that has less hustle in order to get it working ?

Thank you

Comment: You are looking at it from a windows point of view: "installing drivers". That is a bad way when looking from Linux. Linux will rebuild the devices system on every reboot. So when new hardware is added so are the -generic- drivers loaded for that new hardware. You need to use the normal tools to investigate this. For instance: some devices only activate the HDMI input when the specified HDMI port is also selected as source. If so that is not an OS issue. Start with `lsusb` and see if you can track the hardware.Track down the device and then you can make educated assumptions on what to do next.

Comment: http://www.displaylink.com/for-business/common_questions.php  "DisplayLink has not created drivers for other packages, however the Ubuntu driver contains an open source component which is designed to be modified to enable the Ubuntu driver to be repackaged for any other Linux distro by the user community.

Support for DL-1x5 and DL-1x0 devices is provided by the open source udl driver."

Comment: Are you sure you have USB-C and not Thunderbolt 3? I have an XPS 13 (9350) and it does have Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: good question, yes it's USB-C  . Late 2015 Dell XPS 13 comes with USB-C  http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/Notebooks/Dell/Dell_XPS_13_End_2015/Dell_XPS_13_02.jpg  ...college of mine has Dell  XP 13 from earlier 2015 and he has Tunderbolt

Comment: Sorry but the question is about the adapter (so the thing you plug to USB-C) Alhough I can confirm I have Dell XPS 13 late 2015 model and yes it had USB-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like Ubuntnu 16.04 may finally have the fix included http://blog.jimbasilio.me/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-release-dell-xps-13-9350/ (go to "External Monitor" section)

https://thomashunter.name/blog/linux-compatible-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter/

## update

ok I've risked it I spend $90 and bought "KENSINGTON USB-C Mobile Dock" ([link](https://www.alza.sk/kensington-usb-c-mobile-dock-d4528966.htm?o=7) ) and it kinda works. Basically VGA works all the time, HDMI works too but with limited resolution, I still need to spend some time configuring X11 as the hightest revolution by default was 1920x1080.

but the point is it's ok now, at least it works. I'm still running same Ubuntu 15.10 as when I posted this question. I'm planing to reinstall to 16.04 next month, so I'll keep you updated.

Comment: ok running Ubuntu 16.04 now, the dock station I've mentioned works fine all looks good, although I have mid-expensive Asus monitor that has frequency up to 120, yet I can only get 60. Yet at least it works.

Answer (score 4):

I also have the late 2015 Dell XPS 13. The jack is Intel's new multi-purpose connector. It is an integrated USB-C and Thunderbolt 3. So you can use a dongle that operates on either standard. (I'm not allowed to comment or I would put this there).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** I would say this classifies as an answer (though it's a *hardware answer*, it's still an answer)